# wp7 listbox bouncing - items at bottom of list

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've noticed that the last items in my list box don't scroll up freely.  They almost "bounce" when I try to move them up.  The effect is even worse when I have the SIP active.  I can't scroll the bottom items up the screen.  They stay on the bottom of the screen and I can't see them (or they are partially blocked).

Any ideas on how to correct this situation?

```
    <ListBox VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid>

            <TextBox Height="72" Margin="109,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txt1" Text=""  VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="341" InputScope="Text"/>
            <TextBox Height="72" Margin="109,70,267,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txt2" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" InputScope="Number" />
            <TextBox Height="72" Margin="0,70,73,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="txt3" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" InputScope="Number"/>
            <TextBox Height="131" Margin="12,160,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="txt4" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="438" InputScope="Text"/>
            <TextBox Height="72" Margin="12,320,0,147" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txt5" Text=""  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438" InputScope="Text"/>


            <TextBlock Height="30" Margin="47,30,333,0" Name="lbl1" Text="Dosage" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Height="30" Margin="10,90,332,0" Name="lbl2" Text="Quantity" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Height="30" Margin="0,90,142,0" Name="lbl3" Text="Refills" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <TextBlock Height="37" Margin="24,135,212,0" Name="lbl4" Text="Additional Instructions" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Height="30" Margin="24,293,0,0" Name="lbl5" Text="Reason for Taking" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Height="30" Margin="24,385,0,0" Name="lbl6" Text="Consumption Frequency:" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>


            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,417,0,0" Name="lblday1" Text="Sun" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="37" />
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="83,417,0,0" Name="lblday2" Text="Mon" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" />
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,417,272,0" Name="lblday3" Text="Tue" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="37" />
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="203,417,0,0" Name="lblday4" Text="Wed" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" />
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="263,417,0,0" Name="lblday5" Text="Thur" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" />
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="329,417,0,0" Name="lblday6" Text="Fri" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="37" />
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="388,417,0,0" Name="lblday7" Text="Sat" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="37" />


            <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,431,0,0" Name="chkSun" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Width="59" />
            <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="75,431,0,0" Name="chkMon" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Width="59" />
            <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,431,0,0" Name="chkTue" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Width="59" />
            <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,431,202,0" Name="chkWed" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Width="59" />
            <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="255,431,0,0" Name="chkThu" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Width="59" />
            <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="315,431,0,0" Name="chkFri" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Width="59" />
            <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="375,431,0,0" Name="chkSat" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Width="59" />

        </Grid>
    </ListBox>
```

**UPDATE:**

OK, I sort of answered my own question.  At least I found an initial answer to my own question.  What I did to correct the bouncing is to modify the height property in the .

```
<Grid Height="800">
```

Now when the SIP is active the bottom items are visible with plenty of room to spare.
As I said above, I found an answer.  I don't know if it was the right answer.  If you have a better way, please let me know.

When I was testing this, yes, when the SIP is active I can initially move freely to the bottom.  However, when I move try to move back up I get the bounce effect again.  Is there something that I need to add to allow it to move freely up and down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in general is that the Listbox doesn't know how tall it is.  You can solve it by setting an explicit height on it's parent, sure.  A better way to do it would be to define a row for it in the grid:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>  
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <ListBox Grid.Row="0">
    ...
  </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

The Height="*" says the row should take the entire space of it's container.

Comment: After banging my head against the wall, I think I found the same solution.  I will be trying this later on.  Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I answered my own question.  At least I found an answer to my own question.  What I did to correct the bouncing is to modify the height property in the .

```
<Grid Height="800">
```

Now when the SIP is active the bottom items are visible with plenty of room to spare.

As I said above, I found an answer.  I don't know if it was the right answer.  If you have a better way, please let me know.